# Access denied for user 'me'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, permissions, authentication

I am am trying to learn mysql 101. Doing so, I broke my ability to login as root.

At first I could simply connect to mysql by running

```
sudo mysql
```

In an attempt to alleviate a problem, I thoughtlessly copy and pasted some sql into the mysql prompt.

Specifically...

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Now when I try to log in using sudo mysql, I get the error...

> Access denied for user 'me'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

What exactly did I do, and how can I rectify it?

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Now you can probably login by

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

and entering the password from your ALTER USER statement when prompted.

Once you're in the console again you can reset the password to empty like:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '';
```

And it should start to allow you with just `sudo mysql` as before.

Comment: I disagree with your `ALTER USER` statement - this will allow everyone to connect as `root` without a password. It sounds like the original `root` user was configured to use the password-less, but secure socket authentication plugin - this is why they had to do `sudo mysql`.